# How to convert this signature to text (python)

Tags: python, security, data-manipulation, signature

I have made a signature signing app in python. I have little experience with signatures in general, but when I run it, I would like to convert the data to text, (or maybe it is supposed to be bytes? as I said, little experience), However, I have tried to (and looked up about how to convert bytes to string/text) and it either throws an error or doesn't convert the data at all.

Code:

```
# Generate a private key   
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend      
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend()
)

# Sign a message using the key
def sign_string(input_string):
    message = input_string
    signature = private_key.sign(
    message,
    padding.PSS(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
        salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
    ),
    hashes.SHA256()
)
return signature
```

Comment: maybe hashlib might be better for the sha256 hashing... IDK.

Comment: figured it out! just had to add .hex() to the signature and if I want a string, just wrap it in str(). I'm leaving this up, just in case others need this, and yes, I know that you are supposed to sign a file, not string, but it's just an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I see you answered your own question. The alternative is to Base64 encode it with `base64.b64encode()`. The advantage is you’ll get a shorter string than if you represent it as hex.